# how to plot regression line with specification of formula

Tags: r, ggplot2, formula, lm

I'm trying to plot a regression line that passes through the origin. I use the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ISwR)
thuesen
cc <- complete.cases(thuesen)
tcc <- thuesen[cc,]
attach(tcc)
m <- lm(short.velocity~blood.glucose -1)
m
graph <- ggplot(data=tcc, aes(x=blood.glucose, y=short.velocity)) + geom_point()
graph + geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=m)
Error in model.frame.lm(formula = formula, data = data, weights = weight,  : 
objet 'weight' introuvable
```

I don't understand this error message, has anyone a solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the same formula within `ggplot2`:

```
graph + geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~x-1)
```

[image]